# called generated web test code from console application

Tags: c#, asp.net, automated-tests

I had a general question about extracting code from a visual studio web test. I used the "generate code" option of a web test and got the following:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.WebTesting;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.WebTesting.Rules;

namespace SignsOfLife
{
    public class SignsOfLifeCoded : WebTest {

        public SignsOfLifeCoded() {
            this.PreAuthenticate = true;
        }

        public override IEnumerator<WebTestRequest> GetRequestEnumerator() {
            // Initialize validation rules that apply to all requests in the WebTest
            if ((this.Context.ValidationLevel >= Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.WebTesting.ValidationLevel.Low)) {
                ValidateResponseUrl validationRule1 = new ValidateResponseUrl();
                this.ValidateResponse += new EventHandler<ValidationEventArgs>(validationRule1.Validate);
            }

            WebTestRequest request1 = new WebTestRequest("http://localhost/site/client/default.aspx");
            yield return request1;
            request1 = null;

            WebTestRequest request2 = new WebTestRequest("http://localhost/site/login.aspx");
            request2.ThinkTime = 5;
            request2.QueryStringParameters.Add("c", "clientcode", false, false);
            ExtractHiddenFields extractionRule1 = new ExtractHiddenFields();
            extractionRule1.Required = true;
            extractionRule1.HtmlDecode = true;
            extractionRule1.ContextParameterName = "1";
            request2.ExtractValues += new EventHandler<ExtractionEventArgs>(extractionRule1.Extract);
            yield return request2;
            request2 = null;

            WebTestRequest request3 = new WebTestRequest("http://localhost/site/login.aspx");
            request3.Method = "POST";
            request3.ExpectedResponseUrl = "http://localhost/site/user/home.aspx";
            request3.QueryStringParameters.Add("c", "clientcode", false, false);
            FormPostHttpBody request3Body = new FormPostHttpBody();
            request3Body.FormPostParameters.Add("__LASTFOCUS", this.Context["$HIDDEN1.__LASTFOCUS"].ToString());
            request3Body.FormPostParameters.Add("__EVENTTARGET", this.Context["$HIDDEN1.__EVENTTARGET"].ToString());
            request3Body.FormPostParameters.Add("__EVENTARGUMENT", this.Context["$HIDDEN1.__EVENTARGUMENT"].ToString());
            request3Body.FormPostParameters.Add("__VIEWSTATE", this.Context["$HIDDEN1.__VIEWSTATE"].ToString());
            request3Body.FormPostParameters.Add("__EVENTVALIDATION", this.Context["$HIDDEN1.__EVENTVALIDATION"].ToString());
            request3Body.FormPostParameters.Add("Login1$UserName", "username");
            request3Body.FormPostParameters.Add("Login1$Password", "password");
            request3Body.FormPostParameters.Add("Login1$LoginButton", "Log In");
            request3.Body = request3Body;
            yield return request3;
            request3 = null;
        }
    }
}
```

What I wanted to do is basically put this test into a separate service to run throughout the day for purposes of health checking. I basically want to make sure that users are able to log in throughout the day. What process should I use to get the test into something like a console app? I was running into issues with debugging the webtest code. Like how would I correctly call the GetRequestEnumerator method and respond to it from code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**First suggestion:** 
   assumption: you want to run this on a daily basis and make it reusable/extensible for new tests

Throw your test code into a web service and link it appropriately.
Then create a windows service that consumes the service on a daily basis based on whatever interval of time and store the results in some fashion.

If my assumption is incorrect then this is an unnecessary amount of work for something that will not be reused later.

**Second suggestion:** 
    assumption: your tests will only be executed for a period of one day

Simply write a console app to execute the tests at a given interval
write the console app to run a timer class and register a callback event for when the time interval has elapsed. In the callback method you defined, perform the tests needed and record the results.

There is a threading issue that can be handled in a number of ways ... you want you app to continue running all day so you could just use something like this

```
public class tester
{
   public tester()
   {
       //setup timer logic here
       //..
       //..

       var ts = new ThreadStart(run);
       var thread = new Thread(ts);
       thread.start();
   } 

   public void run()
   {
       while (ShouldContinue);
       {
           //do nothing execute keep app going
       }
   }
}
```

then toggle ShouldContinue when you meet your exiting condition ... i would assume the condition would be if the app is running for 24 hours + in this scenario

The second solution really shouldn't take you very long to design and manufacture. But the first will be more time consuming.

hopefully that answers your question or sparks another idea =D

Comment: This is not answering the question. Example: "how would I correctly call the GetRequestEnumerator method and respond to it from code?" is left completely unanswered.